# Having issues with css transforms and javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to use css transforms with js to pull up a list from a link when pressed. The function seems to work when I click the link, but the list does not disappear or go down when I click it for the second time.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, but help would be appreciated!

```js
function one(){
 var j=document.getElementById("start");
 if(j.style.transform=="translate3d(0vw,0vw,0vw)"){j.style.transform="translate3d(0vw,30vw,0vw)"}
 else{j.style.transform="translate3d(0vw,0vw,0vw)"}
}
```

```css
#test a{width:50%; height:auto; overflow:auto; float:left; margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; background:rgba(20,20,20,0.5); }

#start{ float:left; background:blue; width:50%; height:auto; transform:translate3d(0vw,30vw,0vw); transition:0.5s;}
#start ul{width:100%; height:auto; float:left;  }
```

```html
<div id="start">
<ul>
<li> List</li>
<li> List</li>
<li> List</li>
<li> List</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="test"><a href="#" onclick="one()">Click to show</a> /<div>
```

Comment: `translate3d(0vw,0vw,0vw)` --> `translate3d(0vw, 0vw, 0vw)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This check is failing

```
if(j.style.transform=="translate3d(0vw,0vw,0vw)")
```

because the actual value has spaces in between the parameters. Change it to

```
if(j.style.transform=="translate3d(0vw, 0vw, 0vw)")
```

```js
function one(){
 var j=document.getElementById("start");
 if(j.style.transform=="translate3d(0vw, 0vw, 0vw)"){j.style.transform="translate3d(0vw,30vw,0vw)"}
 else{j.style.transform="translate3d(0vw,0vw,0vw)"}
}
```

```css
#test a{width:50%; height:auto; overflow:auto; float:left; margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; background:rgba(20,20,20,0.5); }

#start{ float:left; background:blue; width:50%; height:auto; transform:translate3d(0vw,30vw,0vw); transition:0.5s;}
#start ul{width:100%; height:auto; float:left;  }
```

```html
<div id="start">
<ul>
<li> List</li>
<li> List</li>
<li> List</li>
<li> List</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="test"><a href="#" onclick="one()">Click to show</a> /<div>
```

Comment: 1. Adding / removing a class with the needed CSS would be a better suggestion. 2. The anchor should be a button element.

Comment: Thank you, @takendarkk.

that absolutely worked! 
I wanted to ask one more thing if I may. 

I'm trying to add opacity to the function above, but I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. 


function one(){
 var j=document.getElementById("start");
 if(j.style.transform=="translate3d(0vw, 9vw, 0vw)"; & j.style.opacity=="1"){j.style.transform="translate3d(0vw,30vw,0vw)"; && j.style.opacity="0"}
 else{j.style.transform="translate3d(0vw,9vw,0vw)"; && j.style.opacity="1"}
}